# What's the use of "get" routes "rails generate controllers" created in routes.rb in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When creating a new controller post in rails with command `rails generate controllers post`, routes started with `get` will be inserted into the top of routes.rb automatically like below:

```
  get "posts/index"

  get "posts/new"

  get "posts/create"

  get "posts/edit"

  get "posts/update"

  get "posts/show"
```

We notice that the rails routing works the same after deleting those routes. We just found out that one of routes caused error in rails engine routing and it has to be deleted. We haven't found documents about those automatically generated routes. What's the purpose of those routes and is there any use of them in rails app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the routing working the same after you delete these. If you remove those routes, rails application will not redirect requests to a controller and your site wont work. Do you have other routes the file?

Comment: There is resources :posts in routes.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'get' is the HTTP verb supported by the routing engine.  It's possible to route GET and POST (and the rest) to different methods, even if they hit the same URL.  It's also possible to only support certain verbs for certain URLs (as is happening here).

Regarding their necessity - we'd have to see the rest of your routes.rb file to know.  If you have a default match rule, that likely will take effect if these are removed.

Comment: There is resources :posts in routes.rb.

Comment: The 'resources' line expands to a subset of what you've pasted above.  I'll refer you to the rails routing guide for details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web.  Unless you have specific needs, remove these 'get' lines and just use the resources line.

Comment: Why those routes are added if resources can do the same if not better?

Comment: I believe it depends on how you invoke the generators.  If you use scaffold_resource, it creates the 'resources :posts', versus if you generate the controller by itself with a few actions defined, you get the 'get' version.